# Regex with alphanumeric, space and dash

Tags: regex, tags

I need to construct a regex that will only allow a-z, A-Z, 0-9, dash, space and single quote.  Double space is not allowed inside the string, dash can only be inside a string, double quotes not allowed inside a string. The string can only start with a letter (preferably upper case, if possible) or digit (0-9).
Any suggestions?

Allowed:

```
   "My Test" 
   "My-test"
   "1My-t-es-t"
   "1250 My t-es-t"
```

Not Allowed:

```
   "My  Test" 
   "-My Test-"
   "My T''est"
```

Comment: what have you tried ? nobody here is gonna write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

This might work
https://regex101.com/r/h8ggbH/1

`"[A-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[ ](?![ ])|'(?!')|-(?!"))*"`

Explained

```
 "                     # Dbl Quote
 [A-Z0-9]              # UC Letter or digit
 (?:                   # Cluster
      [a-zA-Z0-9]           # Alphanum
   |                      # or,
      [ ]                   # Space
      (?! [ ] )             #    if not followed by space
   |                      # or,
      '                     # Quote
      (?! ' )               #    if not followed by quote
   |                      # or,
      -                     # Dash
      (?! " )               #    if not followed by dbl quote
 )*                    # Do 0 to many times
 "                     # Dbl Quote
```

Comment: Really awesome answer! Well explained